# Why does Nexus repository doesn't download the required artifacts when using a group repository?

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I use Nexus repository manager and configured the default .../nexus/content/groups/public/ repository and added maven central, codehaus snapshot and an internal respository that I created and have uploaded few artifacts to that.

Then added .../nexus/content/groups/public to mirror in settings.xml. When I do a maven build, maven looks in .../nexus/content/groups/public but does not update org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-6 and reports that it is not found.

But if I remove the mirror from settings.xml, then it looks in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and it picks up all the artifacts correctly.

I have also changed publish url to true. What do I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you added the repositories as `proxy repositories` in Nexus do not forget to add the proxies to the [Repository Group](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-repo-group.html#fig-add-to-group) which you use as [mirror](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for all Nexus requests (public/snapshot) - assumed you have this kind of configuration.